# asp.net mvc change master page & .css dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, customization

Is there a good way to change the MasterPage and/or .css dynamically in asp.net mvc based on the user preferences?

I understand I can change the master name as follows:

```
return View("viewName", "master-name", oModel)
```

and the view using a different contentPlaceHolder perhaps but that requires changing each controller+action.

I'd have to assume there is to be a better way than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's interesting reading http://developmentalmadness.blogspot.com/2009/06/aspnet-mvc-discover-masterpagefile.html

Comment: looks interesting
will try it out !

Comment: worked for the master page
have a theory on making the same change for the css too but will see it i have the time to implement it

Comment: hi, this link is broken, the blog has been moved here's the new url:
http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/06/09/aspnet-mvc-discover-masterpagefile.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have a somewhat simpler method:

```
return View("View", getMasterName());
```

and in my master controller, I have:

```
protected string getMasterName() {
    return (Request.QueryString["tb"] == null) ? null : "Other_Master";
}
```

I use it to display a different template in the case of a thickbox popup vs if, eg, javascript isn't working and the controller is loaded without thickbox.

Comment: there is not a whole lot different from what i have
given the extensibility in mvc, i'm hoping there's another way